# Finding min & max of $ f(x,y,z) = x-2y+z $ bounded by an eliptic paraboloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $$ f(x,y,z) = x-2y+z $$

And $ K $ be the region bounded by

$$ z = 2-0.5x^2-2y^2 $$

Determine the maximum and minimum values of $ f $.

The gradient of $ f $ is
$$ \mathbf{v}=(1, -2, 1) $$

This tells me, as far as I can tell, that the normal vector to the plane at $ (x_{max}, y_{max}, z_{max})$ will be **v**. But I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Hints are preferred over solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the constraint $g(x,y,z)=0.5x^2+2y^2+z=2$ should be used too. In particular, the [Lagrange method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) tells us that the gradients of $f$ and $g$ must necessarily be dependent at the optimal point. The conditions $\nabla f\parallel\nabla g$ and $g=2$ give you enough information to solve the problem.